# How to get rid of TemporaryFolder rule in Junit5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm migrating unit tests from Junit4 to Junit5. In the test I'm using `TemporaryFolder` [rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) from Junit4 API. To keep the test working I added `@EnableRuleMigrationSupport` annotation:

```java
@EnableRuleMigrationSupport
public final class SomeTest {

    @Rule
    public final TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();

   // tests ...
}
```

As I understand, in Junit5 I need to use [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/Extension.html) instead of [rules](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html), but I can't find any replacement for `TemporaryFolder` in Junit5 extensions. Does it exist? How to correctly replace `TemporaryFolder` rule with extension?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [`@TempDir`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html) annotation (JUnit 5.4+), described in [§2.20.1 of the JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-built-in-extensions-TempDirectory). From the user guide (**emphasis** mine):

> The built-in `TempDirectory` extension is used to create and clean up a temporary directory for an individual test or all tests in a test class. **It is registered by default.** To use it, annotate a non-private field of type `java.nio.file.Path` or `java.io.File` with `@TempDir` or add a parameter of type `java.nio.file.Path` or `java.io.File` annotated with `@TempDir` to a lifecycle method or test method.

*Note: This extension was added in version `5.4` and is currently (as of `5.8.2`) experimental.*

Example of using an instance field:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;
import java.nio.file.Path; // or use java.io.File

class SomeTests {

    @TempDir
    Path directory; // may be private since 5.8

}
```

<sup>– [Allow @TempDir fields to be private #2687](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2687)</sup>

Example of using a parameter of a test method:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;
import java.nio.file.Path; // or use java.io.File

class SomeTests {

    @Test
    void testFoo(@TempDir Path directory) {
        // do test...
    }

}
```

***Note:** Constructor parameters are not supported.*

When the directory is created and deleted is described in [the Javadoc of `@TempDir`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html) (documentation quote from JUnit 5.8.2):

> ### Creation
>
> The temporary directory is only created if a field in a test class or a parameter in a lifecycle method or test method is annotated with `@TempDir`. If the field type or parameter type is neither `Path` nor `File` or if the temporary directory cannot be created, an `ExtensionConfigurationException` or a `ParameterResolutionException` will be thrown as appropriate. In addition, a `ParameterResolutionException` will be thrown for a constructor parameter annotated with `@TempDir`.
>
> ### Scope
>
> By default, a separate temporary directory is created for every declaration of the `@TempDir` annotation. If you want to share a temporary directory across all tests in a test class, you should declare the annotation on a `static` field or on a parameter of a `@BeforeAll` method.
>
> ###### Old behavior
>
> You can revert to the old behavior of using a single temporary directory by setting the `junit.jupiter.tempdir.scope` configuration parameter to `per_context`. In that case, the scope of the temporary directory depends on where the first `@TempDir` annotation is encountered when executing a test class. The temporary directory will be shared by all tests in a class when the annotation is present on a `static` field or on a parameter of a `@BeforeAll` method. Otherwise — for example, when `@TempDir` is only used on instance fields or on parameters in test, `@BeforeEach`, or `@AfterEach` methods — each test will use its own temporary directory.
>
> ### Deletion
>
> When the end of the scope of a temporary directory is reached, i.e. when the test method or class has finished execution, JUnit will attempt to recursively delete all files and directories in the temporary directory and, finally, the temporary directory itself. In case deletion of a file or directory fails, an `IOException` will be thrown that will cause the test or test class to fail.

Comment: And what to do with junit 5.3? I'm stuck with an older version...

Comment: I don't think there's a replacement in JUnit versions older than 5.4. You either have to upgrade to 5.4+ or continue using [`@EnableRuleMigrationSupport`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.migrationsupport/org/junit/jupiter/migrationsupport/rules/EnableRuleMigrationSupport.html). Though I suppose you could [write your own extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions).

Comment: With JUnit 5.8 `@TempDir` can be private too - see [Allow @TempDir fields to be private](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2687)